# Where can I find ArcGIS logs when I execute a python script using arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, geoprocessing, log

I'm executing a python script locally on my computer where ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 is installed (Windows 7).
The script uses functions from the arcpy library installed with the ArcGIS Desktop to manage  (crud) and geoprocess data stored in an ArcSDE Oracle database (remote server).

Do you know where I can find the ArcGIS logs related to the execution of this script?

Comment: Is logging turned on in your script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[History logs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002100000035000000) are stored in `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\(Local or LocalLow or Roaming)\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\History`

but to save log history, you have to activate it, using this code :

> arcpy.SetLogHistory(True)

**EDIT:**

For Arcgis 10.0 ArcPy do not support `SetLogHistory()`, so you have to activate it manually like described in [this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//002100000035000000)

Comment: The code doesn't recognize arcpy.SetLogHistory(True).

Comment: For Arcgis 10.0 ArcPy do not support SetLogHistory(), so you have to activate it manually like described in this link http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//002100000035000000

Comment: OK. And if the arcGIS desktop and ArcGIS Server are installed on the same machine, what arcpy library is used? The one installed with the server or the desktop?

If it's the server, where can I find the log files?

Comment: ArcGIS desktop and ArcGIS server uses the same ArcPy library, so you will find log files in the same directory, in both cases.